Pocketbase force user to select an account when loggin in with google
I'm using Oauth2 authentication with Google. When logging in, I don't get prompted to select the user I want to use. It just uses the last one. Now, I want to force the screen to select the user to be shown.
I found answers but not for Pocketbase
